# Lubuntu copying file path instead of file

Tags: file-copy, clipboard, lubuntu, file-manager

I have a newly installed lubuntu 20.04 using pcmanfm as file manager. When I copy a file(or images) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste it in browser (gmail or facebook chat). But when I paste it in file manager, desktop or libreoffice writer, it is pasted properly. What can the problem be? Thanks :)

Comment: This behavior is normal. You are pasting a file in a text field, so it does the only think that's reasonable/logical and pastes the path. What would you have it do?

Comment: @Rayleigh No, we can copy an image file and paste it as image in gmail compose, facebook chat or libreoffice writer. I would want it to paste the image, or drop the file (say it's a text file) in the place.

Comment: In those cases you are right it should (at least in Writer). What's your file manager? Is it Thunar?

Comment: It's PCManFM-Qt

Comment: I am not familiar with it. Nonetheless try using different file managers to find the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Tried using Thunar, still the same issue.